# unable to do tnsping even after having the hostnames under tnsnames.ora

Tags: oracle, oracle-ebs

I was unable to tnsping my oracle EBS source server from my target server.

VISEBS is the source and VISEBST is the target

source tnsnames.ora:

```
VISEBS=
    (DESCRIPTION=
            (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=xx.xx.xx.149)(PORT=1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA=
            (SERVICE_NAME=VISEBS)
            (INSTANCE_NAME=VISEBS)
        )
    )
VISEBST=
    (DESCRIPTION=
            (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=xx.xx.xx.150)(PORT=1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA=
            (SID=VISEBST)
        )
    )
```

target tnsnames.ora:

```
VISEBS=
    (DESCRIPTION=
            (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=xx.xx.xx.149)(PORT=1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA=
            (SERVICE_NAME=VISEBS)
            (INSTANCE_NAME=VISEBS)
        )
    )

VISEBST = (DESCRIPTION=
            (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=xx.xx.xx.150)(PORT=1523))
            (CONNECT_DATA= (SERVICE_NAME=VISEBST)
                     (INSTANCE_NAME=VISEBST))
        )
```

tnsping output on 149:

```
TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 05-APR-2018 06:50:07

Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
/u05/oracle/VISEBS/12.1.0/network/admin/VISEBS_xxxxx/sqlnet_ifile.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp) 
(HOST=xx.xx.xx.150)(PORT=1521)) (CONNECT_DATA= (SID=VISEBST)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
```

tnsping from 150:

```
TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 05-APR-2018 
06:50:21

Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=sal- 
devtl10.hosts.secure-24.net)(PORT=1521)) (CONNECT_DATA= (SERVICE_NAME=VISEBS) 
(INSTANCE_NAME=VISEBS)))
```

all the ssh connections between both the machines have been working flawlessly.

what will be the problem that was causing this.

Comment: You haven't shown the actual `tnsping` commands, or the result of the second one (did that get an error too?). Are the port numbers supposed to be different in the two `tnsnames.ora` files - should they both have 1523 for the VISEBST entry? Where does ssh fit in - are these supposed to be tunnelled over ssh, or direct access?

Comment: for the result of the second command i m getting **TNS-12547: TNS:lost contact**

Comment: yeah i changed the port number to 1523 and then from source it was happening, but from target it was not happening now @AL

Answer (score 1):

EBS servers are configured with [IP restrictions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28337/tdpsg_network_secure.htm#TDPSG40045) (via tcp.invited_nodes in sqlnet.ora).  If this is configured you will only be able to perform a TNS ping from an invited node.  New nodes can be added via an autconfig variable.